# When exactly do I get comment notifications?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, comment-replies

Incredibly, I couldn't find a single, consolidated and up-to-date answer for this question. All I found was people complaining about missing notifications, discussions about changes in the notification system, and questions about `@replies`.

So here is what I think I know:

- If I ask a question, I get notified about all comments, on the question or on any answer.
- If I write an answer, I get notified about all comments on my answer.
- Otherwise, I'm only notified if the comment contains a `@reference` to me

Is that really how it works? Do I get automatic notifications in any other situation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: Thanks. I've seen that answer, but I was hoping for a more straightforward answer to "when do **I** (or **you**) get automatically notified of a new comment". For example, I'm including @Sathya here because I'm not sure you'll be notified. I know the answer is somewhere on [that link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), but I'm just too lazy to find it there right now. That's why I'm asking this, I think we need a separate, simple and clear answer to that simple question.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think the FAQ answers this specific question too well, because it focuses on `@replies` and their syntax. My question here is "I know `@replies` forces a notification, but when else am I auto-notified?".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

- On a question, you will receive notifications automatically for comments on the question only, not the answers.

  - One exception is auto generated comments, like closing as duplicate: you will not get notified of such comments.
- On an answer, you will receive notifications automatically for comments on your answer.
- On any question or answer, you will receive notification when you are pinged (@name).

Pings are slightly more complex, as they are potentially ambiguous.  `@name` will match the eligible user with a name beginning with `name` that most recently acted in the thread.  The following actions make one eligible for receiving a ping:

- Commenting on the post.
- Editing the post.
- (♦ moderators and users using the [dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/295232) only) closing a post.

For the rules on writing a ping, refer to the [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/172958).

There is also an automatic / implied ping:

- If you are the only user to comment on a post, and its author posts a comment without an @notification, you will be notified.