# If a comment triggers a notification, what happens to the notification if the comment is deleted?

Tags: support, comments, email

I'm still somewhat new to SO. I am curious about what happens when I make comments.

As I understand it, if I make a comment a notificatiaon is sent to the user addressed. My two simple questions are:

- What happens if I delete the comment after I make it? Does it disappear from the recipient's notification queue as well? Or does it stick around?
- What happens if I edit my comment? Does only the first version get sent to the recipient? I would assume that's it, as it would be annoying and clog up the other user's notifications queue otherwise, but just want to be sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: I don't think that post actually provides the answer to this question, @TheEstablishment.

Comment: @Pop: Number 9 is the answer to the second question. I suppose the answer to the first is buried in a comment. No, deleted comments don't appear in the targeted user's inbox. Perhaps I should add that explicitly to the body of the answer.

Comment: @TheEstablishment Thanks .. that answers my questions then - I'd accept it as an answer if I could :)

Comment: @TheEstablishment - What question is Number 9 answering?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When exactly do I get comment notifications?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125208/282094)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197393/282094

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An e-mail isn't sent to the user addressed, there's only a notification. This is one of the reasons why Stack Overflow is awesome.

[image: Stack Exchange MutiCollider SuperDropdown]

If the comment is deleted, the red circle still appears, but when you open the inbox, the comment doesn't exist - it points to the previous comment, if applicable, and is not highlighted.

Okay, with some testing now:

- A comment was added, then deleted, and a new comment was added on this answer. I got (2) in the MultiCollider, and of course, the last comment was shown.
- Then another comment was added and deleted. (At least, I think it was.) No notification this time.

But... I've also gotten notifications for deleted comments that even contained their full text. So I'm really not sure what goes on there.

Comment: maybe this is matter of terminology or semantics .. I didn't mean an e-mail is sent to my private SO associated account (e.g.,yahoo or gmail etc), but rather I get a notification that I have something in my SO `inbox` (hence I referred to this as an e-mail). So my question is about that .. sorry if I wasn't clear with the terminology.

Comment: @Levon Yeah, you might not want to refer to these notifications as emails because honestly they're not and you'll just confuse everyone.

Comment: Hey, somebody comment back here and then delete it right away so I can make sure I did this right.

Comment: @lunboks Thanks .. I edited my question to use the right terminology .. always learning new things here :)

Comment: @lunboks: Could you do that again, please? Levon's comment overwrote it.

Comment: @minitech Yeah, I did add another comment and deleted it. My guess is that only explicitly deleted comments disappear from your inbox, while comments with a deleted parent post remain, for whatever reason. Of course I could be wrong and it could be completely arbitrary.

Comment: @minitech thanks for trying this out .. so the bottom line is we don't know for sure .. I wonder if anyone does?