# Do users get notifications when @ was edited in

Tags: support, comments, notifications, comment-replies, comment-edits

I always wondered if users get notified about comments were their name was edited in afterwards.

Example:

I write a comment

> See this link here

then I edit it to

> @someuser: See this link here

Does the user get notified now?

Comment: Just try is here. AFAIK I have did it. And user got notification.

Comment: @hims056 Did you get this? Just edited now.

Comment: @hims056 Is this a notification?

Comment: @hims056: this is a test comment

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees

Comment: @michaelb958 That was my understanding, that it ended up in the profile under responses but no red (1) notification. If this has changed it is a very welcome change

Comment: [At removed] As a related test i'm going to cycle this comment through assorted notifications for all people in this thread. Edit; did anyone other than hims056 (the first @) get this?

Comment: @RichardTingle - Did you edit my name? The Red ball came and went within a second.

Comment: @hims056 I did, that’s interesting, so if you don't notice the fleeting @ its retrospectively removed from your inbox. Probably for the best to avoid people using this as a reply to all facility

Comment: @RichardTingle No red `1` (was away when you were testing), but if I open my inbox your comment is there as it read at the time - just silently.

Comment: Ok, so I think we've got the behaviour nailed down. If at any point @yourname is in a comment you will get a notification in your inbox. **But** you will only get a red(1) notification if @ yourname is *currently* in the comment

Comment: @RichardTingle: Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: @juergend Done, I'll put the other screen shot in when I next get a notification

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After experimentation within this question the current behaviour* has been found to be as follows:

If **at any point** @yourname was in a comment you will get a notification in your inbox.

[image: notification bar]

But you will only get a red(1) notification if @yourname is **currently** in the comment (either originally or by edit), i.e. if @yourname is edited out and you haven't seen the red(1) notification yet it is removed.

[image: notification]

<sub>* See [the old behaviour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74781/172011)</sub>

Comment: So, it's bφrken!

Comment: @hjpotter92 Less than it used to be, the old behaviour was that if the @ was edited in it didn't turn up in your inbox at all. Only in the responses tab of your profile

Comment: @RichardTingle I remember Nick saying long time ago something like "if you edit it into the comment after it was posted maybe it will trigger notification and maybe it won't" - can't find it now though.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd in our testing we were getting real time response to both editing in and editing out notification,  perhaps they've improved it?

Comment: @RichardTingle yep very likely the case, I also don't remember the notification vanish when the comment is deleted/edited to remove the `@` so probably this change also resulted in a more stable code.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, the bit you couldn't find is [in the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/307622) under the section "Can I change who gets notified after the comment is posted?"

Comment: @Wildcard nice find!

Answer (score 17):

Yes. As [@michaelb958](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197393/do-users-get-notifications-when-was-edited-in#comment-624538) and other tested in this same question. I got all those three notifications after their edit.

[image]

Comment: Oh, that is awesome!

Comment: @AndrewBarber - [This is even more awesome!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197393/do-users-get-notifications-when-was-edited-in#comment-624543)