# Will edited comments to one post notify the poster multiple times?

Tags: support, comments, edits, notifications, global-inbox

I checked the [What events trigger an inbox notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353/1355014) and searched for "edit" but didn't find this specific problem about "edited comments".

Since "Another user comments on one of your posts." will notify the poster, I didn't use "@user" in my comment.

Q:

Then when I first write one comment, the post will be notified. After editing the comment, will the poster get notified again or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do users get notifications when @ was edited in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197393/do-users-get-notifications-when-was-edited-in) It's not exactly about editing a comment on a post notifying the author of the post, but it has some information on how edits affect notifications.

Comment: I don't recall ever getting two notifications from the same comment, but I know I've followed the link from my inbox and discovered the comment had been edited (though it's maybe not clear that what happens on the back end is "notify on post and don't bother updating," as you might theorize it's based on the sum of changes, like the grace period).

Comment: @RobertLongson maybe the referred link https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74781/1355014 solves with the time. Then it depends on the timing whether the edited comment will re-notify the poster. Is it that case?

Comment: @AaronBertrand For the "grace period", do you mean that it won't notify again in one range of edit counts or time but it will notify again after some unknown time or edit counts?

Comment: Yes, in that context I meant "updating" to mean "send a second notification on edit." But to clear, this is just conjecture, I haven't looked at code. (Else, I would have posted an answer.) Now, I purposely edit this comment multiple times, and didn't use `@`. How many notifications did you get?

Comment: Also, for the grace period, it's different for posts and comments. For posts, I can commit multiple edits in 5 minutes, and they're combined into one update. Ten minutes later, I can do it again. For comments, there is only the initial 5-minute period where they can be updated. After that, they can only be deleted, or edited by a moderator.

Comment: @zcoop98 I read this link based on the before comments. But I have some confusion as my reply to RobertLongson says.

Comment: @zgc Apologies, that was an auto-generated comment from review!

Comment: @AaronBertrand Maybe I was reading this question, so I didn't get one notification from your comment.

Comment: @zgc I don't think so, but I'm happy to help you test that theory.

Comment: @AaronBertrand 1. Thanks. Then I will keep your recent notification there. Could you edit and I check the result then? 2. BTW, I didn't use "mark as unread" for some time just now. Then the inbox keeps having 2 notifications but their contents are changed. Does this imply the many notifications are combined so that only recent 2 are left? (I have marked these 2 notifications.)

Comment: 1. I can't edit that comment now, because more than 5 minutes passed. 2. I really don't know how to interpret exactly what you did and exactly how the inbox should have worked in response.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Could you help test with this comment. I will edit it multiple times. Test the first time. The 2nd time. The 3rd time.

Comment: I only got one single notification.