# Does a question-asker get automatically notified of comments in this circumstance?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

Under this sequence of events:

1. Someone posts a question
2. I post an answer
3. OP comments on my answer
4. A third party adds a comment to my answer
5. I add a comment to my answer

Does the OP receive automatic notifications for either comment #4 or #5? The actual post in question is [using content_for and and ajax/Jquery to partially update webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713470/using-content-for-and-and-ajax-jquery-to-partially-update-webpage/15713497?noredirect=1#comment22319719_15713497). (I added a manual ping to the OP at the end, because I wasn't sure.)

The best source I could find for when automatic notifications occur I found at [When exactly do I get comment notifications?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/when-exactly-do-i-get-comment-notifications). If I'm reading this correctly, the OP will not get automatic notifications for either of those above events. Is this correct? That post is also over a year old, so I don't know if it's up-to-date with respect to how it works.

I apologize if this is a dupe, but finding details about exactly when automatic notifications occur is difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the OP receive automatic notifications for either comment #4 or #5?

No. The OP is notified on your answer only if that third user pings the OP.

> If I'm reading this correctly, the OP will not get automatic notifications for either of those above events. Is this correct?

Yes!

Answer (score 0):

> No OP will not get notified until and unless you use @ and OP name
>   this will notify him that the comment is related or targeted towards
>   him. Also you will not require your name with @tag to recieve
>   notification as you are owner of the question. You can use only one
>   person name with @ with respect to the reputation point you have in
>   your account.