# Why don't you get a notification when your comment is upvoted?

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

I've read about when notifications are sent from comments, as stated in this question: [When exactly do I get comment notifications?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/when-exactly-do-i-get-comment-notifications)

However, sometimes I like to know when others upvote my comment. It tells me that others are thinking the same why I am, and while I don't think it's deserving of reputation, it gives me confidence that my post is being read and that others agree. In addition, I am more likely to follow up on a comment thread (that I am not being constantly tagged in) if my comments are upvoted, but sometimes it is easy to forget a comment you left on a post, and it is sometimes hard to go find it again (a meticulous process just to see if it has any upvotes).

I understand that notifications can sometimes be a logistical nightmare for systems like SE, but would it be feasible to get a notification when your comment is upvoted? If not, what would be the reasoning behind such a decision (not that I necessarily disagree with it, just wondering)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'd be close to impossible to make it a *good* user experience - maximize signal to noise.

It's true that there are a handful of times when I'd want to know if a comment of mine were upvoted, but of the over 3,000 comments I've made across Stack Exchange, I really, *really* don't care when pretty much all of them are upvoted. So, maybe one percent of the time, it'd be giving me a relevant notification.

The predominant effect would be to cause most people to ignore their notifications.

Comment: Would it be possible to have a notification for something like "Your comment on _xyz_ has received 5 upvotes?" or something along those lines?

Comment: Rather than a notification for every upvote, do one for every 5 or 10

Comment: @ThePickleTickler [I wrote you a query that I think should speak for itself.](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/525249) Left column: the user ID. Right column: the number of notifications this system would have generated.

Comment: You couldn't have convinced me more, thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help!